# People Picker field is not setting the values on the edit form

Tags: 2013, people-picker, edit-form, edit

I don't know why the people picker field is not setting the values of an item in the edit form, i can see that the column has a value when i see the properties of the item but when i try to edit the item the people picker is just empty.

Someone knows what this is happening?

Comment: What is the value you are setting in the people picker field? Name or Email or ....?

Comment: Well I don't know... It supposed to be the value Sharepoint works with... Because as i said... I set the value in the new form and I can see the value on the view form (the name... but i don't know well how sharepoint stores a people value) but i cannot see it in the edit

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots of the issue to get a clear idea?

Answer (score -2):

Try this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/17db4d9a-590f-4d4d-ab83-9d7d50cf6e31/sharepoint-2013-july-2014-cu-people-picker-fields-empty-in-edit-forms?forum=sharepointadmin). I think there is some workaround to solve this issue.